# jQuery doesn't add class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Simple scroll down -> change navbar sequence using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
     var c, currentScrollTop = 0,
     navbar = $('nav');
     $(window).scroll(function () {

        currentScrollTop = a;
        if (c > 650) {
          navbar.addClass("scrollUp");
          console.log("Showing navbar", c, navbar.hasClass("scrollUp"));

        } else if (c < 700) {
          navbar.removeClass("scrollUp");
        }
        c = currentScrollTop;
    });
}
```

Console log outputs current scroll and "false" where needed. Class just doesn't add up.
Fyi I'm bad at jQuery and it's the only thing I have in my react app.
scrollUp in CSS adds a background-color transition to nav, making it opaque.
I noticed that sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't and I can't identify the problem. Haven't seen it working for a while now.

Bonus:

```
$("#toProjects").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#projects").offset().top -75
      }, scrollSpeed);
      return false;
  });
```

This scrollTo function doesn't work as well.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar.scrollUp {
  background-color: #000000;
  transform: background-color 0s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code hosted somewhere like codesandbox?

Comment: Does the nav element have navbar class already? You are accessing the element by "nav" but the css is applied to any element that has both .navbar and . scrollUp classes.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using jquery to select 'nav', but you refer to the class 'navbar' in your css?

Comment: `currentScrollTop = a` <-- what is `a`? I am sure the console is full of errors. Where is `c` being set?

Comment: @Mark It's live on rendemental.firebaseapp.com
I used this code from some stackoverflow fella, who tried the same thing. It was working fine before and stopped just now. No idea why.

Comment: @NawedKhan Yes it does, nav is the tag and navbar is the class inside

Comment: @epascarello Everything is set before the function for... reasons. I'm not goot at jQuery, I can't tell if it makes a lot of difference or not. It worked fine before, but now it just seems to ignore adding the class

Comment: Where is it in the code above? You are not reading the scroll position as the user scrolls.

Comment: The output of scrolling is fine, it detects it perfectly. Problem is that the class is not added at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `currentScrollTop` to `a` but `a` is never defined.

Edit:
I see you have different code on your website than you've posted here.
You're not connecting to your navbar correctly. 
Try this instead.

```
var c, currentScrollTop = 0, navbar = $('#navbar');
```

`$('nav')` is looking for elements with the name 'nav', of which, none exist on your page. same as calling `$('div')` or `document.querySelector('div')`.

`$('#navbar')` grabs the elements on your page where the id attribute is set to navbar.

This fixes the class not being added part but I think you'll need to work with the css a bit to actually see the affect take place.

Comment: Accidentally edited your post instead of replying. It's defined and it's not the problem

Comment: If this solved the issue please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by integrating jQuery code directly into ComponentDidMount() function inside React component. That way it re-engages and works fine